# Why does dateFormatter adjust dates?

Tags: python, matplotlib, dateformatter

I have a dataframe from a couple of json files, which looks like this:

|  | summary-id | calendarDate | vo2Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | x36a5cdb-5cb66c80 | 2019-04-17 | 48 |
| 1 | x36a5cdb-5cc39b80 | 2019-04-27 | 46 |
| 2 | x36a5cdb-5cb12680 | 2019-04-13 | 46 |
| 3 | x36a5cdb-5ca7ec00 | 2019-04-06 | 46 |
| 4 | x36a5cdb-5cba6100 | 2019-04-20 | 46 |

When I plot the data using

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))

ax.plot(user_metrics_df.calendarDate, 
        user_metrics_df.vo2Max, 
        color='tab:red')
ax.set(xlabel='calendarDate', ylabel='Vo2Max', title="Ontwikkeling van Vo2Max")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(interval=2)) 
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

I get a good plot, but when I add the line

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d%m%y'))
```

the dates in the xlabels are adjusted to dates ranging from 1969 to 1971. I can't find why that happens and what I should do to prevent that. Anyone?

Comment: Can you show a sample from your data?

Comment: The data is in the original question.

Comment: I'm asking for the original format, you might be using something different from [ns].

Comment: The dataframe is a concatenation of several json files with this data: 
[{"summaryId": "x36a5-5cb60", "calendarDate": "2019-04-17", "vo2Max": 48.0}, 
{"summaryId": "x36a5-5cc80", "calendarDate": "2019-04-27", "vo2Max": 46.0},